# on Cockroach DB Is there a way to mimic the behavior of UDFs?

Tags: cockroachdb

Having a Postgres function to raise an error if the return value of digest() doesn’t match an expected value. Being Cockroach DB does not support UDFs, is there an alternate way to mimic such behavior?